# Prevent 2 forms from being submitted?

Tags: javascript

I have two forms on the same page and I'm preventing each from being submitted multiple times with this:

```
onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true;"
```

Using javascript, can I similarly prevent form #2 from being submitted if form #1 has already been submitted, and vice-versa?

Comment: You need to check this at the server end as well. Also why not just have the one form?

Comment: The thing with client side is that you shall never ever under no circumstances trust them. If this is a "safety measure" you will have to do the validation on your server. But that aside,
You can access the different forms buy giving them an id (id="form1" and vice versa) Then, when submitting, simply disable the other form with document.getElementById("form2").disaled = true;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable to save state of the forms

```
 var disabled=false;
```

and

```
  onclick="if(!disabled){this.form.submit(); disabled=true;}"
```